# <html> Поехали Div блоки

Tags: css, html, sass, блок

Нужно сделать блок с инструкцией на сайт. Второй блок поехал (отображается на 10px ниже остальных), как исправить без использования float?

```css
.manual {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 20%;
}
.steps {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 410px;
  margin: 20px 5px 0px 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="manref manual">
  <h1 class="text">КАК ЭТО РАБОТАЕТ?</h1>
  <div class="attline"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="steps">
    <img src="img/step1.jpg" class="stepimg">
    <h2 class="steptexth text">Шаг №1</h2>
    <h3 class="steptext text">Нанесите клеевой раствор и уложите первую плитку. Установите по два зажима под плитку с каждой стороны, отступив от края плитки около 50мм.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="steps">
    <img src="img/step2.jpg" class="stepimg">
    <h2 class="steptexth text">Шаг №2</h2>
    <h3 class="steptext text">Уложите следующую плитку с одной из сторон, как показано на рисунке.</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

  </div>
  <div class="steps">
    <img src="img/step3.jpg" class="stepimg">
    <h2 class="steptexth text">Шаг №3</h2>
    <h3 class="steptext text">Вставьте клин между плитками и верхней частью зажима. Зафиксируйте его так, чтобы нижняя часть клина плотно прилегала к плиткам и стороны плиток выровнялись.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="steps">
    <img src="img/step4.jpg" class="stepimg">
    <h2 class="steptexth text">Шаг №4</h2>
    <h3 class="steptext text">Для удаления зажимов после высыхания клеевого раствора — просто ударьте по верхней части зажима, вдоль шва плитки.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="steps">
    <img src="img/step1.jpg" class="stepimg">
    <h2 class="steptexth text">Шаг №5</h2>
    <h3 class="steptext text">Нижняя часть зажима останется под плиткой. Соберите клинья — их можно использовать повторно до 50 раз.</h3>
  </div>
```

(классы `text`, `manref`, `manual` для оформления шрифтов и цвета)

Comment: p.s. Все картинки одинаковых размеров.
Если использовать float, то как сделать чтобы следующий блок отображался "с новой строки"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно как именно "поехали" блоки. Но думаю

```
.steps
   vertical-align: top
```

может вам помочь

Comment: Помогло, благодарю